How can I remove the shell navbar in a view?
I am developing an app in MAUI, and I have some shells to be able to navigate in different views
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LasCarnalasApp"
    x:Class="LasCarnalasApp.AdminShell">


    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent
            Title="Añadir Producto"
            Icon="add_product_icon.png"
            Route="ProductsPage"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ProductsPage}" />

        <ShellContent
            Title="Ver Ganancias"
            Icon="profit_icon.png"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:ProfitsPage}"
            Route="ProfitsPage"/>

    </TabBar>
 

</Shell>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LasCarnalasApp.ProductsPage"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>


I know this because the content scrolls down, and if I put a Title="Something" in the Shell it appears. What can I do?
I tried to put it in the same Shell Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False" but it didn't work
Image without navbar
Image with navbar

I've just tested it with the code and it doesn't show up the issue you mentioned. Everything works fine. Can you give the shell code for the second image showing something?

Do you use Shell.TitleView to display the Views? What is the expected result?
